# Compute ‎$‎\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln(‎\Gamma‎(n+x+1)) - \ln(‎\Gamma‎(n+1)) - a\ln(n)\Big)‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, special-functions

‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎How to compute that

‎
‎
‎‎‎‎$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln(‎\Gamma‎(n+x+1)) - \ln(‎\Gamma‎(n+1)) - a\ln(n)\Big)$‎‎,

‎
for ‎‎$‎x>0‎$, ‎‎$‎a\geq 0‎$
and
‎

$‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{x+a}{k^2+k(x+a)} -‎ ‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎‎\frac{x}{k^2+kx} - ‎‎‎\frac{a}{x}\Big)$‎‎,
‎‎

for $‎a\geq 0‎$ ‎. Anyone can help me? thanks.
‎

Comment: Where is this question from? What did you try?

Comment: I brought an example for a theorem that I was able to solve to this extent, but I couldn't go any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use Stirling's approximation that $$\ln(\Gamma(n+r+1))\sim\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi n) +(n+r)\left(\ln(n+r)-1\right)$$
When $n\to\infty$

Comment: Rohan Shinde.‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎I have resolved but I couldn't ‎continue:‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ $‎\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln‎\frac{‎\sqrt{2\pi n} (n+x)^{n+x}‎}{‎\Gamma‎(n+1) n^a} -‎ ‎(n+x))‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎.  
  On the other hand, I know ‎$‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{x\to\infty}‎\frac{‎\Gamma(x+1)‎}{(‎\frac{x}{e})^x ‎\sqrt{2\pi x}‎‎} =‎ ‎1‎$‎.‎

Comment: @koohyareslami Use the Stirling's approximation for $\ln(\Gamma(n+1))$ as well. Then make cases as $a\lt x$, $a\gt x$ and $a=x$. You will notice that the limit exists only if $a=x$.

Comment: Rohan Shinde.By ‎using the Stirling's approximation for ‎$\ln\Gamma(n+1)$ ‎and ‎‎$‎\ln‎\Gamma‎(n+x+ 1)‎$, ‎I‎ ‎‎have ‎‎

Comment: ‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{n\to\infty}(‎‎\frac{1}{2}‎‎\ln(2\pi n) + (n+x)\ln(n+x) - (n+x) - \frac{1}{2}‎‎\ln(2\pi n) - n(\ln(n) - 1) - a\ln(n))=‎$‎‎
‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{n\to\infty}(‎\ln ‎‎\frac{(n+x)^{n+x}}{n^n n^a} -‎ ‎x)$.‎ ‎Now ‎if ‎‎$a=x$ ‎then ‎‎
‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\lim_{n\to\infty}(‎\ln ‎‎\frac{(n+x)^{n+x}}{n^{n+x}} -‎ ‎x)‎$, ‎but‎ I couldn't ‎continue.
‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: @koohyareslami $$=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}\right)-x$$ But since $\ln$ is a continuous function thus $$=-x+\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}\right)$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Use that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+x}=e^x$$

Answer (score 1):

By using the definition of the Gamma function $ \Gamma(n) = (n-1)! $ we can rewrite the above equation as:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\ln(\Gamma(n+x+1)-\ln(\Gamma(n+1)-a\ln(n)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\ln(n+x)!)-\ln(n!)-\ln(n^a)) =  $$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\Big(\frac{(n+x)!}{n!n^a}\Big)$$
The term $ (n+x)! $ can be rewritten as:
$$ (n+x)! = (n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)\cdot n! $$
the limit now becomes:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\Big(\frac{(n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)}{n^a}\Big) $$
In the product of the numerator the highest degree will be of order $x$:
$$ (n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1) = n^x+a_1n^{x-1}+...+a_xn+a_{x+1} $$
Where the $a$'s are just constants. When this product is divided by $n^a$ we will have three cases to consider:

> **Case $1$**: $ a>x $. In this case the fraction:
>   $$ \frac{n^x+a_1n^{x-1}+...+a_xn+a_{x+1}}{n^a} \rightarrow 0_+$$
>   as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and thus the limit:
>     $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\Big(\frac{(n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)}{n^a}\Big) = -\infty$$
>   **Case $2$** : $ a<x $. In this case the fraction:
>   $$ \frac{n^x+a_1n^{x-1}+...+a_xn+a_{x+1}}{n^a} \rightarrow +\infty$$
>   as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and thus the limit:
>     $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\Big(\frac{(n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)}{n^a}\Big) = +\infty$$
>   **Case $3$**: $ a=x $. In this case the fraction:
>   $$ \frac{n^x+a_1n^{x-1}+...+a_xn+a_{x+1}}{n^a} \rightarrow 1$$
>   as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and thus the limit:
>     $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \ln\Big(\frac{(n+x)\cdot (n+x-1)\cdot...\cdot(n+1)}{n^a}\Big) = 0$$

For the second problem the two sums converge by the ratio test and thus you can add them together and you get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{x+a}{k^2+k(x+a)} -‎ ‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎‎\frac{x}{k^2+kx} 
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a}{(k+x+a)(k+x)} = $$ $$ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+x+a)}-\frac{1}{(k+x)}$$
This is a telescoping series and all the terms after $k$ surpasses $a$ will cancel out. The part that survives are the value for the first $k < a$ values:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+x+a)}-\frac{1}{(k+x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{a-1}-\frac{1}{k+x}$$
As this sum is finite and in the limit $x\rightarrow\infty$ it will go to zero and the limit is also going to 0.

Comment: Dinno Koluh. Thanks. But for the first problem, $‎‎‎n+x+1\notin‎‎‎\mathbb{N}‎‎$‎.

Comment: Dinno Koluh. Why  ‎$‎‎‎‎‎‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{k+x+a} -‎‎‎ ‎‎\frac{1}{k+x}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$ is a telescoping series?

Comment: Because there are the same terms which will cancel out.

Comment: we have $‎‎‎‎‎‎\sum_{k=1}^\infty ‎\frac{1}{k+x+a} -‎‎‎ ‎‎\frac{1}{k+x}=‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎‎
‎$‎‎\frac{1}{x+a+1}‎-‎\frac{1}{x+1}‎+‎\frac{1}{x+a+2}‎-‎\frac{1}{x+2}+‎\frac{1}{x+a+3}‎‎-‎\frac{1}{x+3}‎+‎\cdots‎‎$‎, but there are not the same terms which will cancel out.

Comment: **I have done this thinking that $a$ is in the set of the integer numbers**. After $k$ becomes equal to $a$ the negative terms inside the sum will start to cancel out the positive terms but the positive terms will always be $a$ steps in front of the negative terms but as $k$ goes to infinity that will not matter since the only terms left will be the first $a-1$ negative terms of the sum.

Comment: You are right, but I assumed $‎a\in‎\mathbb{R}‎‎‎‎‎$.

Comment: Yes, you should maybe point that out in the question for others.